# "No tests found" for instrumentation tests for Lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

My instrumentation based (espresso) tests don't run on Lollipop+ devices and emulators. They correctly run on any other platform. I have the same symptoms as the guy in this thread - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/QW5SuzQizNk

- My tests are in src/androidTest/java/
- I've set testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
- The test classes are @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
- Individual tests are annotated with @Test

I can execute a ./gradlew connectedCheck and the tests run well on a device with KitKat, but when I try to run the same tests the same way on a device with Lollipop I get...

15:02:15.784 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] Tests on XT1095 - 5.1 failed: **Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'**

15:02:16.011 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] 
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > **No tests found.[XT1095 - 5.1] FAILED**

15:02:16.011 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] **No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).**

Comment: are you still facing a problem?

Comment: Yes, it's still not solved.

Comment: @piotrek1543 see my accepted answer below, it's solved! :)

Comment: It's working and you've put it in answer, so I add +1. Have a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally it started working. I followed this answer:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/QW5SuzQizNk/mWdaEuuCCQAJ
which links to:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/271

Basically this was the problem:

I incorrectly used **compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'**

instead of correct
**apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'**